# Advance Installer Auto update issue

Tags: advanced-installer

Currently I am deploying auto updater service for my msi file.Auto update works fine and check for update correctly and download installation package from repository but when it installs it its .exe file is not extracted from installation package and shows error like :

Error:Update installation failed.
Some of th updates failed to install properly.[image: Here is the error that i got]

Please Help me to get rid out of this stuff !!

Answer (score 1):

I experience this issue when I would want to determine if an update was available based on *[Configuration with File Size Check](https://www.advancedinstaller.com/user-guide/updates-configuration-examples.html)*; my *updates.txt* file on the server side resembled this

```
;aiu;
[MLMS]
Name = MLMS
URL = http://servername/winapps/dev/mlms/ai/mlms.exe
Size = 15485915
Description = This update fixes issues related to ticket #999
Feature = Added comments section to Chemical Process
FilePath = c:\Program Files (x86)\YOVA\MLMS\MLMS.exe
Version = 1.31.0.0
```

When end users would trigger *Check for updates* on the client side - it would always assume an update was available and if you went through the update/repair process at the end they would get the error mentioned in this question.

My solution was to use the *Configuration with Version Given by a Registry Value* method. This actually worked better since my build server increments the version on every release. I updated my *updates.txt* by removing property values that did not apply to the configuration such as `File Path` and adding those mentioned in the documentation (e.g. `RegistryKey`); Adding unessary values yields weird behavior.

```
;aiu;
[MLMS]
Name = MLMS
URL = http://servername/winapps/dev/mlms/ai/mlms.exe
Size = 15485915
RegistryKey = HKLM\Software\Wow6432\YOVA\MLMS\Version
Version = 1.31.0.0
Description = This update fixes issues related to ticket #999
Feature = Added comments section to Chemical Process
```

Overwall I belive the issue may be how you have the *updates.txt* configured, also all settings on the *updates.txt* file must be valid or you get that error. For example, initially I had omitted the `\Wow6432\` path from my registry value on my *updates.txt* server side file and this error would surface, once corrected the error went away and the update detection worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you a two steps investigation:

1. you should first manually install the updates setup and see if the upgrade installation succeeds (also try to create an installation log too)
2. then you should try to deploy the updates setup through auto updater and launch the updates setup with a log command; then check the updates installation log file and make sure there is nothing wrong during upgrade

Comment: I had checked update installation and it works correctly .. but will you please tell me how to maintain log file of installation ?

Comment: to create a log file all you have to do is to run the updates setup with a command line like this:
`/L*V <path to log file>\log.txt`

Comment: just add a command line like the above in your updates configuration project in the command line field of the updates installer. this way when the updater will launch the updates setup it will launch it with the specified command

Answer (score 0):

Modify the properties in update config. please refer the attach image.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cD0gO.png)